# Referencing sheet in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to excel vba and I have some questions regarding referencing a worksheet

I noticed that when I used

```
 Worksheets(3)
```

The worksheet would be obtained according to the sequence of the worksheet in the workbook

When I used

```
Worksheets("Name")
```

It would be retrieved according to the name of the worksheet

However, I found that both approach is troublesome because for method 1, I need to fix the sequence of the worksheet. Once I dragged the worksheet around, the reference would become incorrect.

Method 2 would need me to fix the work sheet name , which is not that flexible.

I noticed that at the left panel of VBA editor, under the Microsoft Excel Objects, whenever the worksheet is created, a new sheet like
Sheet1 (Name) would be created.

Is there any way that I could reference the worksheet based the the Sheet1 variable, which I could fixed it so that I could freely drag the sheet around or change the worksheet name?

Thanks.

Comment: Chris has already answered your question. however, just to let you know, I answered a similar question few days ago. Have a look at this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923439/subscript-out-of-range-error-after-renaming-sheets/9923775#9923775

Answer (score 0):

The name you refer to is called the `CodeName`.  You can refer to a sheet by this name.

Eg, for your example `Sheet1 (Name)` can be referenced as

```
Worksheets("name")
```

or

```
Sheet1
```

Eg `Worksheets("name").Activate` or `Sheet1.Active` would both work

Note that you can change this name to something meaningful in the Properties window of the VBA IDE, but you can't change it at run time

Comment: Note that name Sheet1 and Sheet1 are completely different properties. Name is a property of the worksheet and Sheet1 is a member of VBAProject. You can confuse everything by renaming the worksheet named `Sheet1`to `Sheet3` and then in the immediate window enter `?Sheet3.Name` the result returned is `Sheet1`